# jquery selector select all

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using jQuery selectors to show what is selected. `$(selector).addClass('jquery_green');`

// select all tables (works)

```
html > body > table
```

// select second table, fourth row, first column (works)

```
html > body > table:eq(1) tr:eq(3) > td:eq(0)
```

// select all tables, fourth row, first column **(doesn't work)** Can you tell me please what is wrong?

```
html > body > table tr:eq(3) > td:eq(0)
```

The only alternative what I found (really stupid):

```
var baseSelector = "html > body > table";
var selector = "tr:eq(3) > td:eq(0)";

$(".jquery_green").removeClass("jquery_green"); 

var index;
for (index = 0; index < 10000; ++index) {
    sel = baseSelector + ":eq(" + index + ") " + selector;
    $(sel).addClass('jquery_green');
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Why are you `:eq()`ing 10000 times?

Comment: and how are you selecting table rows, by clicking on them?

Comment: @kangoroo: [Selecting](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)

Comment: @BoltClock♦: Because I don't know how many tables are on page.

Comment: @kangoroo: I use jQuery click event to select elements on page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with using more than one `:eq()` in the same selector, but I think your selector

```
html > body > table tr:eq(3) > td:eq(0)
```

is finding the fourth *occurrence* of `html > body > table tr` document-wide, which would only give you *one* `tr` element, then finding that `tr`'s first `td` child. If I understand `:eq()` correctly, then that would result in exactly one `td` element even if you have more than one table.

Given your structure you can probably just replace `:eq()` with `:nth-child()` and `:first-child` which don't limit by occurrences like `:eq()` does:

```
html > body > table tr:nth-child(4) > td:first-child
```

And some suggestions: you can remove the `html >` bit because it's redundant, and in case you have nested tables it would be helpful to add a `> tbody >` between your `table` and `tr` to avoid matching any nested rows/columns within your top-level tables:

```
body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:first-child
```

Comment: Works, thank you! Acceptable solution for me is: html > body > table tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(1)

Answer (score 0):

there is no alternative but to iterate:

```
$("html > body > table").each(function(){
$(this).find("tr:eq(3) > td:eq(0)").addClass("jquery_green");
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `each()`?  I don't think there's any need to do so.  Can't you just write `$("body > table").find("tr:eq(3) > td:eq(0)").addClass("jquery_green");`?

Comment: as per the provided code, i think user has multiple tables on page and he wishes to select 3rd row from every table